# Seeking complete documentation of the Google gitkit identitytoolkit Javascript API

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

By looking at the minified source code at http://www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js

...I found the following methods for which there is no documentation
at https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/setup-frontend

```
google.identitytoolkit.signIn()
google.identitytoolkit.signOut()
google.identitytoolkit.manageAccount()
google.identitytoolkit.start()
google.identitytoolkit.setConfig()
```

While some of the names are self-explanatory it would be useful to have:

1) A documentation of their parameters and callbacks.

2) And what are the setConfig/start methods for?

3) Is there a callback once the API found and rendered an old but valid gtoken cookie?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page covers the most commonly used ways of invoking the web api for the majority of applications: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/setup-frontend

Here is a quick summary to help you get going:

google.identitytoolkit.signInButton(element, config): This will either render the toolkit navbar: the sign in button if the user is not logged in or the user card if the user is logged in. The element provided will be the container of that object. The config object contains the configuration as described in the documentation. If in sign in mode, the button is clicked, it will redirect to the widget url page where the start method below is triggered.

google.identitytoolkit.start(element, config, opt_postBody): This will render the toolkit widget in the element provided. This will be used in the widget url page. The configuration will need to be provided as described in the doc above. The optional post body is used to complete sign in for some identity providers like Yahoo. On sign in success, this will either redirect to static sign in success url in config or call a sign in success call back function if provided. If a sign in success url parameter is provided in the widget url. On successful sign in, it will override the value of the static sign in success url.

google.identitytoolkit.setConfig(config): this will set dynamically the config field. Keep in mind the start and signInButton are run on load so this may be more useful with the methods below which are run on demand.

google.identitytoolkit.signOut(): this is triggered dynamically to sign out the user, using the config supplied in setConfig or as set in signInButton. This will redirect to the sign out url as provided in config or call the sign out callback function if provided in config. Useful if you are providing your own sign out button.

google.identitytoolkit.signIn(): same as signOut but for signing in a user dynamically. Useful if you are using your own sign in button. This will redirect to the widget page url with mode set to select as set in config.

google.identitytoolkit.manageAccount(): This is used when the user is logged in and they want to manage their account (change email or password). It will redirect to the widget url in manage account mode. The widget url in config will be used. Useful if you are providing your own manage account button.

As for your 3rd question, if I understand this correctly, you are asking how to detect that a user is logged in. You can check the id token string saved in the browser cookie (default name is gtoken). You can then use the gitkit client libraries on github to verify the token. Check the doc site for those links. For example, if you are using python on your backend, you can call the method:

gitkit_user = gitkit_instance.VerifyGitkitToken(self.request.cookies['gtoken'])

If successful, this will return a user object.

Comment: Great answer, but this should be added to the documentation.

Comment: The best documentation I've found is the unminified source code: http://www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit-debug.js